# How is iterator different from a pointer during the deallocation of memory in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory-management, iterator, c++98

I have a class "DMRecSessionObj" whose objects are dynamically allocated using new and stored in a map.

```
static std::map<string,DMRecSessionObj*> mapExpSessData;
DMRecSessionObj* dmRecSessObj = new DMRecSessionObj(atoi(p_callNum),atoi(p_totCalls), sessionKey);
mapExpSessData.insert(std::pair<string,DMRecSessionObj*>(sessionKey,dmRecSessObj));
```

During the deallocation of memory, I use the below obvious method

```
delete dmRecSessObj;
dmRecSessObj = NULL; //to prevent it from being a dangling pointer
```

But I am little bit confused while trying to deallocate the memory using iterator as below:

```
std::map<std::string,DMRecSessionObj*>::iterator itr_del = mapExpSessData.find(tmp_sessionId);
if (itr_del != mapExpSessData.end()){
   mapExpSessData.erase(tmp_sessionId);
   delete itr_del->second;
}
```

In this case, should the iterator itr_del be somehow set to NULL? As normal pointers can result in dangling pointers if not set to NULL, how would the iterator behave in this case? Is anything more need to be done in this case to be safe?
Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: The iterator itself is not a pointer rather being used to reference a pointer. The only extra thing that you can add for this code to be safer is making `itr_del->second = NULL;`

Comment: There is a different problem than you are asking about. You must do the delete before the erase as the erase invalidates the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `mapExpSessData.erase(tmp_sessionId);`, the node in the map that `itr_del`  points to has been deleted.  Calling `delete itr_del->second;` is then Undefined Behavior because you try to access deallocated memory.

You need to delete the value in the map first, then delete the node in the map:

```
delete itr_del->second;
mapExpSessData.erase(itr_del);
```

The code block the iterator is in should be small at this point, and the iterator itself going out of scope so you shouldn't need to do anything with it to clear it out.  But if you really want to you can assign the default value for its type back to it.